# How do I optimize TeamViewer?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I've used crossloop before to remotely control my computer from a laptop. 
And I didn't experience lags. Then I decided to use team viewer because it can also remotely transfer files and it is easier to use. But I experience lags, what might be the cause of this?

I'm using granola on the desktop computer which I control with the laptop and set the cpu to use minimal power in exchange for lesser power consumption. 
Can it be one of the causes? Because I didn't know of granola yet when I have crossloop installed.

How do I optimize team viewer?

Comment: It seems like the first test would be to disable Granola and then compare the teamviewer and crossloop.  It's hardly an equivalent comparison if one had run without Granola and the other one with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some options concerning optimization in TeamViewer. Based on your network connection, you can choose to optimize between speed and quality, a higher quality requires higher bandwidth. You can also use custom settings like color range from gray-scale to 256 colors to true color, etc. Make sure that TeamViewer is set to Optimize Speed option. It optimizes the speed of the connection, but the quality will be reduced.

The lagging problem is mostly due to the internet speed. If your computers' internet connection speed is lowered by the running programs which connects to internet in the background or update processes (Windows update, antivirus updates, etc.), this results in shrinkage in bandwidth and causes lags in TeamViewer. If Granola does not consume your internet connection at all, it should not be responsible for the lags. Another reason for lagging may be the slowness on the TeamViewer servers, and this happens occasionally.

[image]