# teamviewer display is slow to refresh

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, speed, teamviewer

I'm using teamviewer from time to time to connect my portable computer with my desktop computer when I need to check on something (personal use).

One of the main things I've been noticing is that it is quite slow transfering the screen updates that keep happening. This happens more frequently when I'm moving full windows or when I open a window or when watching a small movie clip.

I've tested the lowest maximum p2p speed I ever got in the last week between both and it is the desktop's upload speed of 6MB/s with the ping of 40ms (usually ~15 ms).

With this I was expecting to have very sharp image and fast transfer speeds which is not what is happening.

Just to clarify, both computer's individual core's CPU is not reaching its peak (25%) while teamviewer is active, so the encryption and decryption is not the cause.

Why my connection between both computers so slow?

Comment: It's been a while since I used TeamViewer, but, did you change the quality etc in the teamviewer options? Or is this the same as changing the speed?

Comment: That changes the speed, for sure but I'm still puzzled how come 6MB of bandwidth is not enough to stream a video (teamviewer even compresses and optimizes, so the stream speed is in the worse case scenario!)

Comment: What I'm saying is that it becomes barely acceptable when I reduce the quality to the full minimum. If I do a simple video test, it is still unable to keep up (as an example).

Comment: Thank you, that is very clear. Please update the video and graphic AND chipset drivers on both machines.

Comment: The display drivers were already up-to-date, so I updated only the chipset. I'll test for a while and I'll give feedback after testing.

Comment: Please ensure this is the case for *both* machines.

Comment: Yep, I ensured. They are updated now on both machines and I see no changes

Comment: I'm afraid, this is going to be slow. Do you experience this issue with every computer you check to and from? What if you remote in the other way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11534/discussion-between-brunoais-and-dave-rook)

Comment: @DaveRook is not responding me. Anyone else is able to help me?

Comment: Well I thought Team Viewer was intended for remote support and not for multimedia streaming...

Comment: It has the meeting mode :). Anyway, meanwhile I forgot about this question. I solved it in a workaround that is outside the scope of this question. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Disable Hardware Acceleration on video card settings.

Answer (score 1):

TeamViewer connects both machines to a TeamViewer cloud server that [relays the screen updates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14280/how-team-viewer-establish-remote-desktop-connection). This almost guarantees that you will be able to have two computers connect. This may explain the "slowness" you are experiencing. I notice the same issue as well. Turning down the quality helps a little, but it is not good enough for streaming video. Try alternative remote desktop software such as Chrome Remote Desktop, or the dozens of other free software out there. Except for PC-over-IP (PCoIP), I have not seen any remote desktop protocol that comes close being right in front of the computer. Take a look at this video that compares [RDP vs PCoIP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MifH_Jp8aK0) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

When remote desktop is slow or it has long response lag...

**IF** you already checked that it's NOT a problem with:

- the quality settings in TeamViewer ([optimization info](https://superuser.com/questions/160745/how-do-i-optimize-teamviewer))
- the internet speed or somebody is transferring (up/down)
- the individual core CPU usage ([taskman or procexp](https://superuser.com/questions/493827/windows-8-task-manager-single-core-cpu-graph-only))
- the memory full or swapping (please reboot PC)

**THEN** if TeamViewer is still slow & delayed I would suggest:

- Then try disable hardware acceleration on video card settings on the remote computer. For example, on Windows 7 this is the path: Control Panel > Display > Adjust Resolution > Advanced Settings > Troubleshoot > move the slider left to disable.

This solution worked for me, after long research, I guess the reason are the screen updates mentioned on sunk818 message.

Answer (score 0):

You use free edition for non commercial use?Remember that TV is not connecting two machines but video stream goes through TV server (slow if you are free user, and faster if you are premium user and payed for it). I get 80/20 Mbps LTE net access and was expecting near realtime remote work but i was terribly wrong, its only slightly better than on my previous 5/1 Mbps connection.